# phpmyadmin - cannot create database

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I have a localhost installation of wordpress and have finished a website there. I want to make a second website so I created a new folder and downloaded and unzipped  WordPress in the folder. I am now trying to create a database for the second website.

I have opened phpMyAdmin: 
1. When I click on create database it says ‘no priveliges’ but will not give me any further information. 
2. If I go to the top and click on server:localhost, I get two messages:
  a. Version information: 4.1.4, latest stable version: 4.1.11.
  b.The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. To find out why click here.
      1).  Clicking ‘here’ gets me this:
             PMA Database ... not OK [ Documentation ]
             General relation features Disabled
        a).  Clicking ‘Documentation’ gets me this:
                      404 Not Found
                      The requested URL /phpmyadmin/pmadb was not found on this server.

Being new to this, I am not sure what to do next and am afraid of doing something that will damage the work I have already done on my 1st site. My questions are:
1. how to update phpMyAdmin since I don't see that option and will that clobber my existing site in any way. 
2. can anyone tell me why I can't create a database and what to do about it.

(note, I read somewhere to edit config.inc.php in phpmyadmin but inside of the files it warns not to edit it and I didn't know what change to make anyway).

Any advice will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to log in to phpMyAdmin with username of 'root' (along with a previously established password).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to log in to phpMyAdmin with username of 'root' (along with a previously established password).